# I cannot clear syslog but I can remove it?

Tags: syslog

Why doesnt `sudo /dev/null > /var/log/syslog` and `sudo > /var/log/syslog` work, while `sudo rm /var/log/syslog` works?!

Answer (score 79):

`truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog`

working for me on 18.04. Got it from here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191156

Comment: Works with the Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 25):

There are two main problems.

One problem is that `/dev/null` isn't a command, so running `sudo /dev/null` can't succeed. You need `sudo [a command]`. In this case, you probably want `sudo cat /dev/null`.

The other problem is that `>` separates things into a full command on the left and a file on the right, so the **full command** on the left is `sudo cat /dev/null`, and `sudo`'s job is now done once it runs `cat /dev/null`.

That means that the `>` is running as your user, not under `sudo`. Your user doesn't have permission to write to `/var/log/syslog`, so this will fail.

You need some way to run the entire line `cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog` under `sudo`. Well, `>` isn't a command or anything. It's something the shell handles, so you need to have a shell handle that redirection symbol properly. You can do that with `sh`'s `-c` option: `sh -c 'cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog'`.

Now that you have everything together as one command, you can have `sudo` run the entire thing:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog'
```

Comment: No command is needed, the `>` is enough. The OP just got an error but did truncate the target file, see my answer.

Comment: Agreed. Except that "**sudo** allows a permitted user to execute a *command* as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy."

Comment: True, but irrelevant. The OP would get the same error with or without `sudo`, it comes from `bash`, not from `sudo`.

Comment: The first command worked for me with root login.

Answer (score 18):

The command you are thinking of is probably

```
> /var/log/syslog
```

Nothing else is needed. In bash and other shells, the `>` will immediately truncate the file, emptying it. However, when you run this:

```
sudo /dev/null > /var/log/syslog
```

The system is attempting to run `/dev/null` as a command and you will get this error:

```
sudo: /dev/null: command not found
```

Note, however, that despite this, `/var/log/syslog` **has actually been emptied** because, as I said above, the `>` is enough, no command is necessary.

Comment: no does not work,. i get the permission error using the > /var/log/syslog and as mentioned with sudo it does not work either.

Comment: @ThomasCovenant sorry, but I have no idea what you are running. If you are running `sudo > /etc/syslog`, then yes, of course you will get a permission error. The `>` isn't being run as root, it is not part of sudo. If you run `sudo -i` to get a root shell and _then_ run `> /etc/syslog` it will work. The `>` isn't a command, so it isn't affected by adding a `sudo` in front of it.

Comment: ah, yes it works with sudo -i

Answer (score 3):

truncate: The truncation process basically removes all the contents of the file. It does not remove the file itself, but it leaves it on the disk as a zero byte file.

Clear ALL Content of Syslog with:

sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is

```
sudo tee </dev/null /var/log/syslog
```

Or if you prefer a [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat):

```
cat /dev/null | sudo tee /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I noticed a 14GB syslog file in my 22.04 (jammy) 6.2.0-34-generic then I landed in here. I found a different solution from the man pages and it worked. So wanted to share whoever will encounter same issue -not a problem but a preference- with the late versions of Ubuntu.

I have just edit `/etc/logrotate.conf` file, tweaked a couple of lines. `weekly` to keep the logs for 2 weeks only and `size 3G` to limit them under 3GB and `compress`.

```
# /etc/logrotate.conf
# see "man logrotate" for details

# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 2

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# size
size 3G
```

And the result is syslog file is divided into a couple of multiple syslog files, which have no more than 40MB, and made ~80MB total now. (amounts depend on the machine's logging history).